# The mathematics behind AlphaGo AI and Google Deepmind

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

in case you are following the tech news, Google's AlphaGo beat the world Go champion Lee Sedol, not once but twice.

Here is the link of the game 2 review: http://gogameguru.com/alphago-races-ahead-2-0-lee-sedol/

My friend asked me about how the mathematics is doing works behind AlphaGo's AI. I know it is machine learning, and Google Deepmind uses the term "deep learning", but can't quite elaborate the connection of it with a certain theorem in math. Machine learning is one possible area I would like to pursue in my Mathematics graduate study. Here I appreciate if you guys can tell me a few direction I could follow in the newest mathematics behind this. Thanks.

Comment: If you are interested in machine learning, then you should start to become familiar with theoretical computer science and/or artificial intelligence. Machine learning is a topic covered in an introductory artificial intelligence programming course [although like many topics covered in introductory courses, it's a very large topic that extends far beyond the initial course].

Comment: Machine Learning is not really an area of mathematics. It uses methods from mathematics, computer science and most notably data science.

Comment: As an aside: this is not a particularly relevant question on Math.SE (although it is hard to know this without knowing where it is relevant). In principle, this is on topic at [cs.se], though there are relatively few questions (only about 400) on machine learning. StackOverflow itself has several thousand. I'm not sure which is a better community for further investigation.

Comment: You probably want to ask this on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in starting your journey in Artificial Intelligence, I suggest to get your hands on *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*, by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig, which comes recommended by the Machine Intelligence Research Institute of San Francisco.

It is a really in-depth introduction to the topic, with very few prerequisites. Plus it has tons of well-thought exercises.

Comment: The Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach book, while really fine, has _very_ little to do with how DeepMind works.